# Popup hidden in parent element

Tags: html, css, popup

[image]

I created a some number of li's and each having it's own popup. While clicking on each link respective popup will open. While scrolling the popup will get hide (requirement done by me). I have set height of 400px to ul as it's mandatory for my website. The popup of last li is getting hidden. Can you say how to show the last popup of visible li's (while scroll li changes) on top without hiding it using only CSS. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLy3xc6k/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('ul li a').click(function(){
  if($('p').is(':visible')) {
   $('p').fadeOut();
   $(this).parent().find('p').fadeToggle();
  }
  else
  {
  $(this).parent().find('p').fadeToggle();
  
  }
 });
 $('ul').scroll(function(){
  $('p').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
ul {height:400px; overflow:auto; border:2px solid #aaa;}
ul li {list-style:none; padding:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
ul li a {position:relative;}
ul li p {display:none; width: 100px; position: absolute; right: 0; background: #fff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; z-index: 9;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
  <li> Hello World <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup  <p> New popup screen to check </p> </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.wrapper ul li:last-child p{
   bottom: 22px;
 }
```

try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLy3xc6k/2/